# what is an agent node in aks

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I found the mention of an agent node in the aks documentation but i'm not finding the defition of it. can anyone please explain it to ? also want to know if is it an azure concept or a kubernetes concept.

Regards,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads  "To run your applications and supporting services, you need a Kubernetes node. An AKS cluster has at least one node, an Azure virtual machine (VM) that runs the Kubernetes node components and container runtime."

Comment: @MarkusMeyer so the agent node is no more then a compute node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes the term `node` refers to a compute node. Depending on the role of the node it is usually referred to as `control plane node` or `worker node`. From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/):

> **A Kubernetes cluster consists of a set of worker machines, called nodes**, that run containerized applications. Every cluster has at least one worker node.
>
> The worker node(s) host the Pods that are the components of the application workload. The control plane manages the worker nodes and the Pods in the cluster. In production environments, the control plane usually runs across multiple computers and a cluster usually runs multiple nodes, providing fault-tolerance and high availability.

`Agent nodes` in AKS refers to the worker nodes (which should not be confused with the [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/), which is the primary "node agent" that runs on each worker node)